# How do I make a simple graph in HTML/Webmatrix?

Tags: html, razor, graph, webmatrix

How do I make a column graph or chart in HTML using Webmatrix and Razor? I have absolutely zero knowledge of javascript, which most Q & A seem to refer to.

I want to show a thermometer rising as the daily sales rise in our office. The data will come from my Razor SQL query, which already displays a simple numerical value. Now I have been asked to show this graphically, so salesmen can see how close to the sales target they are.

I have a daily sales figure, as a variable called nett: `var nett = [sequel queries to get data]`

Is there a way to create a simple graph to represent this var in cshtml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it could help in your project, but exists a Chart Helper for WebMatrix.

You can find more informations in this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/data/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good luck with webMatrix and http://highcharts.com but it may well be overkill for your project.  It's a javascript library for charting.  A popular alternative is http://perfectwidgets.com/

Comment: interesting links, may help someone else with more js knowledge.